# TidTcpClient ReadBytes method not returning data

Tags: tcp, client, indy

My client receives strings where the first 4 characters of the string define the length of the message.

Example string: 0034PDCS00001700kg00000000kg00001700kg

- The message length is 34
- The message is PDCS00001700kg00000000kg00001700kg

I'm finding that reading is blocked when using either TidTcpClient.ReadString method or ReadBytes method even though there's enough data.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Would someone please give me advice?

```
FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 4, False);// this gets the length OK
len := BytesToString(Buffer).ToInteger; 
FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, len, True);// this blocks and doesn't move on
sReceive := BytesToString(Buffer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown works perfectly fine for me when I test it.  The length and the data are read correctly without blocking. So something else is going on, either the data being received is not what you have shown here, or the problem is happening in another piece of code that you have not shown.

In any case, you can simplify the code you have shown by using `ReadString()` instead of `ReadBytes()` to read both values:

```
len := FClient.IOHandler.ReadString(4).ToInteger; 
sReceive := FClient.IOHandler.ReadString(len);
```

Comment: I have it in an anonymous thread and the first time through its ok but the next read doesn't work.  I've tried it using the read string method and get the same problem.  Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: You have not shown enough code or sample data to diagnose that, but my guess is that there is probably something in the data of the first message that you are not accounting for correctly, or your thread code has a logic bug somewhere, that is causing your reading of the second message is to get out of sync with the real data being sent.

Comment: Thanks Remy I'll have to come back to this another time but all the thread does is this then synchronise with the main thread the response. I put a tidlogevent on the client and the data is right but I'm tired and it's late now. Perhaps when I come back to it after a good nights sleep I'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: The problem was in the call to synchronize the data, an exception was being raised and not handled, I wasn't seeing any exception messages so the thread just stalled and stopped working. I put a try except in the synchronize method and handled the exception and it's working fine.  Thank you so much for your help once more.